# Graph Theory - K-factor

Tags: graph-theory

Does there exist a 47-factor of $K^{100}$?

I wonder because in graph theory $k^9$ is 2-factorable  for a $k$-regular spanning graph. Is there a way to come out with such a thing?

Comment: Asking if an $m$-factor exists is different than asking if a graph is $m$-factorable. Which do you mean? The difference is somewhat analogous to asking whether a given prime $p$ divides $n$ versus the question of factoring $n$ into prime numbers. The former is easy, the latter is hard.

Comment: @Casteels: $K_{100}$ can only be $47$-factorable if $47$ divides $99$.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk I agree that $K_{100}$ has a $47$-factor of course, but it's not clear that it is $47$-factorable.

Comment: @Casteels: It is clear that $K_{100}$ is *not* 47-factorable. That is why your comment surprised me.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk Oh doh, I hadn't yet checked the obvious necessary condition! Really my first comment was directed at getting the OP to make sure he understood what he was asking.

Answer (score 1):

Factoring complete graphs is completely solved by the "Walecki construction"
(Google is your friend).

It says that $K_{2n+1}$ has a decomposition in $n$ Hamiltonian cycles
and $K_{2n}$ has a decomposition in $n-1$ Hamiltonian cycles and a perfect matching.

This means that for even $n$ you can build any factor you like.

For odd $n$ you can build any even factor you like (for odd $n$ there cannot
be an odd factor, since that would results in an odd number of vertices with odd degree).

So indeed, there does exist a 47-factor of $K_{100}$.